# EL1018 does anyone know what it is?

Tags: ac, adc, power-electronics, opto-isolator, converter

Does anyone know what this product is?

[image]

Comment: Your phone (I assume) takes a very nice sharp macro photo (+1 just for that) but it could be improved by cropping off the bottom part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everlight [EL1018 photo transistor](https://everlighteurope.com/photo-transistor/3158/el1018tb-vg.html) ([optocoupler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator)).

You can guess it's an optocoupler by a few clues, like package type, isolation slots in the PCB and most obvious, the component designator (OC2).

Comment: yes i thought so too
thank you